# How to repeat a character (m) to fill the browser window

Tags: html, css, repeat

I am looking to fill the browser window with a single character across the browser window.

The closest answer to a similar question is contained in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bKuVe/):

CSS:

```
.line{
    border-bottom:1px dotted black;
    position:relative;
    height:16px;
}

.line span{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    background:white;
    bottom:-2px;
    height:100%;
    padding:0 5px;
}
.line .price{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}​
```

HTML:

```
<div class="line">
    <span class="title">name</span>
    <span class="price">123.23$</span>
</div>
<div class="line">
    <span class="title">name</span>
    <span class="price">123.23$</span>
</div>​
```

How would I swap the dotted line for a character (m)?

Comment: Using leaders: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/leaders.en.html

Answer (score 0):

To remove the dotted line you would just have to remove the code in the CSS

```
line{
    border-bottom:1px dotted black; <--remove this part of the code
    position:relative;
    height:16px;
}
```

Comment: Thx David. Is there anything I could put within that group to repeat a letter?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a single char as background of the whole page just create an image with the char on it the size depends how big/small do you want it to look like.

Then with the image m.jpg

Do

```
Css
html{
  background-image: url("path/to/m.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```